# IIS server help

Tags: perl, iis, ftp

I'm trying to automate access to a website that get reports from a Microsoft-IIS/6.0 server, or at least I assume that because that is what is appearing in the HTTP Headers. So if the website connects this server, does it **download the file via FTP**? Is there any way that I can find out the commands being sent form my browser?

The weird thing about the website is that it uses **Crystal Report ActiveX viewer**, is that client side, is there any way that I can control the viewer through **PERL**?

Also, this might be a really dumb question, but does **IIS use SQL/MySQL?**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to watch the traffic being sent between your browser and the server.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/
Firebug for firefox
Chrome has it built in by hitting ctrl+shift+i
http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper for IE
F12 in IE will show developer tools (look under network tab)
http://www.wireshark.org/ for watching any network traffic from any application